# add_custom_target not executing with multiple executable in a CMakeLists file

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I got a situation where another `Makefile` is executed from a `CMakeLists.txt` file.
Here is my `root` directory structure.

```
.
├── client.cpp
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── proto_lib
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── math.proto
└── server.cpp
```

This is a simple `grpc` test code where I am trying to compile a `proto` files using a `Makefile` create a static library. And then link that library to the final targets in the `CMakefile`. Makefile is working fine. CMakefile is also working fine with one executable.

Here is the `CMakefile`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(client-server)
message(STATUS "Compiling Network Function : ${PROJECT_NAME}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

message(STATUS "Project Directory: ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")


set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(LIB_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/proto_lib/libmylib.a)



add_custom_target(libmylib.a ALL
                    COMMAND make
                    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/proto_lib
                    COMMENT "grpc headers and libraries are generating..."
)



add_executable(server server.cpp)


set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -Wall -g")
set(BASIC_LIBRARIES "-lpthread")
set(CMAKE_LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE ON)

set(LIBDIR "/usr/local/lib")

find_library(proto_location NAMES protobuf PATHS ${LIBDIR})
find_library(grpc_location NAMES grpc++ PATHS ${LIBDIR})
find_library(grpc_reflection_location NAMES grpc++_reflection PATHS ${LIBDIR})
find_library(dl_location NAMES dl PATHS ${LIBDIR})
find_library(grpc_location2 NAMES grpc PATHS ${LIBDIR})

if(proto_location)
  message(STATUS "protobuf library found at " ${proto_location})
endif()
if(grpc_location)
  message(STATUS "grpc++ found at " ${grpc_location})
endif()
if(grpc_reflection_location)
  message(STATUS "grpc_reflection found at " ${grpc_reflection_location})
endif()
if(dl_location)
  message(STATUS "dl found at " ${dl_location})
endif()
if(grpc_location2)
  message(STATUS "grpc found at " ${grpc_location2})
endif()

target_link_libraries(server ${proto_location}
                            ${LIB_FILE}
                            ${grpc_location}
                            ${grpc_reflection_location}
                            ${dl_location}
                            ${grpc_location2}
                            ${BASIC_LIBRARIES}
)
```

When I enter the command make after CMake . in the root directory.
it starts with following output...

```
Scanning dependencies of target libmylib.a
[ 33%] grpc headers and libraries are generating...
[ 33%] Built target libmylib.a
etc.. etc..
```

and it succeeds.(The internal `Makefile` creates header files and static objects using `proto` and `grpc` libraries. After that `server.cpp` can include the headers from inside the `proto_lib/` folder and CMake build succeeds)

But when I add one more executable at the end of `CMakeLists.txt`,

```
add_executable(client client.cpp)
target_link_libraries(client ${proto_location}
                            ${LIB_FILE}
                            ${grpc_location}
                            ${grpc_reflection_location}
                            ${dl_location}
                            ${grpc_location2}
                            ${BASIC_LIBRARIES}
)
```

and then `cmake .` `&&` `make`
does not start with internal Makefile build. Instead, it starts with `client` build.

```
Scanning dependencies of target client
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/client.dir/client.cpp.o
/home/deka/Academic/gemini/learning/client_server_async/advanced1/client.cpp:10:10: fatal error: proto_lib/math.grpc.pb.h: No such file or directory
 #include "proto_lib/math.grpc.pb.h"
```

Because `proto_lib/Makefile` is not executed first in this case therefore `math.grpc.pb.h` is not generated and that is what the above error is showing.

My question is: Why adding one more executable does not trigger the internal `Makefile` build at the start?

Thanks!